# Comparing each value in a column to the value in the column next to it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm creating an expenses spreadsheet, and I want to be able to compare what each person has paid on each item, to what is owed. If it's `<` what's owed, it will be red, if `=>`, green. I know I can manually conditionally format each cell to do this, but I'm looking for a solution I can use to simplify the sheet for month-to-month editing, with potential to add new expenses or remove them without having to later manually conditionally format the new expense.

I've looked into a few others with similar questions and tried some custom formats. First I went with the simple "if less than column [whichever it is next to] set color to red" and no luck, and one suggested a formula like this: =`($H2>=$G2)*($H2<>"")` though honestly I can't say I fully understand it. I have a grasp on it to a certain extent due to my coding background, but not quite enough. I feel this would be way easier if I was coding and could just use a for each statement...

I expected the cells (specifically for the greater than function) to be green, but actually it's counting all cells as less than the ones next to them, regardless of the values.

[Imgur images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOOZf.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs on [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is that the conditional formatting is offset by 1 row because you trying to apply it on range **H1:H13** but formulas you use works with range **H2:H** & **G2:G**. therefore do it like this where you start from **H2**:

[image: 0]